# OpenGL onCreate fragment view in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, opengl-es, oncreate

I've created OpenGLRenderer.java class and placed some code in it, shows no errors. Then I placed this code for creating a view in RoomFragment.java fragment:

```
public class RoomFragment extends Fragment {

/** Called when the fragment is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GLSurfaceView view = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    view.setRenderer(new OpenGLRenderer());
    setContentView(this);
}}
```

But I'm getting

> The constructor GLSurfaceView(RoomFragment) is undefined

and

> The method setContentView(RoomFragment) is undefined for the type RoomFragment

errors. Aren't those methods implemented in header? I'm guessing the reason for that is that this is not an activity, but a fragment which is active only on button click of a previous fragment (which is active on a main activity menu selection).

How do I go about this? How do I create GLSurfaceView in fragments layer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GLSurfaceView needs to be related to an `Activity` by giving it a `Context`. `Fragment` does not extend from `Activity` and from the looks of it, you're trying to create a `GLSurfaceView` right from inside it.

Also, `setContentView` must be called from an `Activity`, essentially what you're saying is 'I want this Activity to be displayed in the way `**View` is telling it to'. Therefore you have to call the method from the Activity itself.

Try either putting the `GLSurfaceView` inside the `Activity` from where you call the `Fragment`, OR use the `Fragment`'s `getActivity()` method to retrieve the `Activity` it's bound to.

The second solution would end up looking like this:

```
public class RoomFragment extends Fragment {

/** Called when the fragment is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GLSurfaceView view = new GLSurfaceView(this.getActivity());
    view.setRenderer(new OpenGLRenderer());
    this.getActivity().setContentView(view);
}}
```

I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, let me know if it works!

Comment: I understand :) I had to take a step down from the fragment in order to get the context. It's OK now, thanks!